# No puedo agregar www al dominio con htaccess

Tags: aplicación-web, .htaccess, dominio

Estoy usando laravel, y subi el proyecto al servidor y puedo acceder al dominio tanto por miDominio.com como www.miDominio.com. y quiero que siempre agregue el www.

El htaccess lo tengo de la siguiente manera...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$    
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Probé mil codigos de htaccess y no puedo redirigir automaticamente a www.

Answer (score 1):

Las expresiones regulares están correctas y se cumplirían, pero tus condiciones evitan que se realice la redirección.

1. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$` - Verificas si en la URI solicitada aparece la ruta `/public/`,
2. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]` -  Si se cumple la condición aplica la regla, ahora observa las banderas que colocas al final de esta condición:

   - `[QSA]` significa agregar, la condición se agrega a las existentes.
   - `[L]` significa *last*, o **última** regla en inglés. Después de aplicar esta regla, el archivo `.htaccess` deja de procesarse.
3. Ya no tiene caso que se verifique la siguiente condición, porque ya encontró la bandera `L` que detiene todo.
4. Por otro lado, la redirección siempre detiene el procesamiento de las reglas siguientes, porque en estricto sentido `example.com` y `www.example.com` son dos dominios diferentes.

### Solución

Elimina la marca `L` de tu primera regla.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$    
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Puedes consultar todas las opciones de las reglas de redicción en la [documentación oficial](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicacion, hice lo que dijiste y sigue sin agregar el www. 
Probe con esa regla ahora y tampoco agrega, no se si sera algo de ubuntu o nose...


 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio.com.ar [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio.com.ar/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: ¿Reinicias el servidor httpd después de cada cambio? Recuerda que es necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba la segunda linea a cambiarla por RewriteBase

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$    
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```